# What walls and roof are Kosher for a place to be obligated in Mezuza?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, home-house

For a place 4x4 Ama, what should the walls of a dwelling be to obligate the place in Mezuzah:

- How many walls are required?
- Can they be partially or completely transparent?
- What height should they be?
- Are workarounds that count as Mechitzah (Lovud, Gud Asik) good as walls?
- Should there be a roof?
- How much of the space should the roof cover?
- How far can the roof be from the walls?

Comment: Are you speaking of a fixed dwelling? Is that a theoretical question or do you have some sort of dwelling in mind?

Comment: @mbloch if you remember my previous question (about Succah) I'm trying to understand what counts as a "dwelling" in Judaism in different applications.

Comment: Check the Kitzur chapter 11

Comment: There is a sefer on hilchos mezuzah, חובת הדר (or something similar), that should go through all of these points.