# What areas of Halochos require definition of a house/dwelling?

Tags: halacha-theory, home-house

Following [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109611/what-walls-and-roof-are-kosher-for-a-place-to-be-obligated-in-mezuza),

What Halochos require defining a Kosher dwelling/house, like "is such a house Kosher for Y"?

For example, we can surely ask it for a Succah, or a Mezuzah or for legitimate renting. Are there additional realms?

Comment: Off the top of my head: maaser, tzaraas, eiruvin

Comment: @heshy korban pesach, (eruvin is techmuin and chatzerot ftr) arguably avelut and chanukkah, zekher lechurban

Comment: @DoubleAA stoning a cheating naarah hameorasa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemora Sukkah 3a-3b concerning the need of 4x4 amos (cubits) in a house:

> תנו רבנן בית שאין בו ארבע אמות על ארבע אמות פטור מן המזוזה ומן המעקה ואינו מטמא בנגעים ואינו נחלט בבתי ערי חומה ואין חוזרין עליו מעורכי המלחמה ואין מערבין בו ואין משתתפין בו ואין מניחין בו עירוב
>   ואין עושין אותו עיבור בין שתי עיירות ואין האחין והשותפין חולקין בו
>
> House without 4x4 amos:
>   - Is exempt from **Mezzuza**,
>   - ... **Railings** around the roof.
>   - It cannot be: impure with **Tzoraas**,
>   - ... sold for eternity in a **walled city** (i.e past the jubilee).
>   - One cannot: **go back from war** if he built such a house, or
>   - make an **Eiruv** for it or in it or
>   - make a **Shituf mevuos** or
>   - **Eruv Techumin** between 2 cities, and
>   - brothers cannot **divide such a house**.

The Midrash Sifri Devarim 22,8 regarding *Meakeh* adds:

> בית שאין בו ד' על ד' – פטור מן המעקה ומן המזוזה ומן הערוב ואין עושין אותו עיבור לעיר ולא טיבול למעשרות ואין נותנים לו ד' אמות לפתחו הנודר מן הבית - מותר לישב בו
>
> A house without 4x4 amos....
>   - does not make fruit that enter into it susceptible to **tithing** (i.e one can eat those fruit without taking Teruma or Maaser unlike a regular house),
>   - one does not take a courtyard 4x4 Tefachim in front of it for usage  (when inherited with other sibling from a larger estate), and
>   - one who vows not to have benefit from "houses" can have benefit from it as it is to small be catogorised asa "house".

Comment: Probably the nedarim part changes depending on the society

Comment: @heshy the reason for 4x4 is mentioned on the daf quoted because  a person cannot lie down properly on a bed and live normally in a smaller space. Nowadays also we have such needs of being able to live normally so there does not seem to be any change regarding most of sosciety as to the definition of the minimum house

Comment: Great, thank you, I suppose this list isn't full, though.